# Is pci an special IO device?

Tags: x86, operating-system, pci

pci is an io device because we can use I/O instructions to read and write its registers to I/O ports(0xCF8~0xCFC), it connected to the system bus. pci has its own local bus, some devices that follow the pci standard (e.g. pci bridge, pci graphics card, network card, pci hard disk) connected to the pci bus, right?

Answer (score 4):

> Is pci an special IO device?

PCI is a standard. It describes:

a) the physical shape and mechanical details of a PCI slot (e.g. how long it is in millimeters)

b) a "bus segment" consisting of a set of wires an the electrical signals on those wires (voltage, frequency, ..)

c) a higher level communication protocol primarily consisting of packets, to describe what bytes mean on "bus segments".

d) how packets are routed from one "bus segment" to another (through bridges that connect bus segments); to create a PCI bus from segments.

e) a method of identifying and configuring devices (PCI configuration space); which mostly has very little to do with the bus itself.

> pci is an io device because we can use I/O instructions to read and write its registers to I/O ports(0xCF8~0xCFC),

Those IO ports belong to the PCI host bridge (a device between the CPU's local bus and the PCI bus). The PCI host bridge isn't part of the PCI bus (and PCI devices aren't part of the PCI bus) even though it connects to the bus and even though it's part of the PCI standard; in the same way that my house and isn't a road (and the nearest shop isn't a road) even though my house connects to a road.

Graphically (depending on lots of things, including which PCI because "PCI conventional" is quite different to "PCI Express"), a computer might look like:

```
       RAM
        |
       Memory                         ISA/legacy   ISA/legacy
 CPU   Controller                     Device       Device
  |     |                              |            |
  -------                 ISA or LPC-----------------
  |     |                 Bridge
 CPU   PCI Host            |
       Bridge------------------------
                  |        |        |
                 PCI      PCI      PCI to PCI
                 Device   Device   Bridge----------------
                                               |        |
                                              PCI      PCI
                                              Device   Device
```

..and the PCI bus in this computer (which is 2 "bus segments") looks like this:

```
                           |
             ------------------------
                  |        |        |

                                         ----------------
                                               |        |
```

.. and the local bus is this part:

```
  |     |
  -------
  |     |
```

While I'm here (with reference to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113732/some-problem-about-pci-io-devices-cpu-bus)); in computers that had a "north bridge" chip and a "south bridge chip" (mostly the 1990s); the "north bridge" might be the memory controller and PCI host bridge, plus a few faster built-in PCI devices maybe; and the "south bridge" might be the "ISA or LPC bridge" plus all of the built-in legacy devices (PIC chip, PIT chip, ..). Over time everything in the "north bridge" moved onto the same chip as the CPUs (starting in around 2000) and the "north bridge" ceased to exist; and now everything in the "south bridge" is also doing the same (and doesn't exist in some modern systems). Fortunately software has no reason to care where things physically are (which chip).

Comment: "and the PCI bus in this computer (which is 2 "bus segments")"            why not are 3 "bus segments"...... does the bus where the ISA/legacy device is located not count?

Comment: @golangboy: Originally (early 1990s when computers still had actual ISA slots) that was a "PCI to ISA bridge" and the ISA bus isn't a PCI bus. When motherboards stopped having any ISA slots it became a "PCI to LPC (low pin count) bridge" and the ISA bus became a "whatever the chip designed felt like using internally inside their chip" bus (the only thing that matters is it behaves the same for software), where "whatever the chip designed felt like" isn't going to comply with PCI standards for no reason (more likely to be similar to ISA).

Comment: *"Everything in the "north bridge" moved onto the same chip as the CPUs (starting in around 2000) and the "north bridge" ceased to exist".* AMD used separate north/south bridge chipsets until 2011 ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_chipsets)).

Comment: So ... in the diagram, the middle one is the PCI global bus, the top one is the ISA local bus, and the bottom one is the PCI local bus, right ?

Comment: @golangboy: Top left is the local bus (very fast, CPU specific/non-standardized, possibly point-to-point links instead of a common bus), top right is ISA/legacy bus (old, slow). The PCI bus is 2 "bus segments" (middle and bottom right). A computer (e.g. a larger server) can have 2 or more PCI host bridges resulting in 2 or more PCI buses; each PCI bus can have 256 "bus segments", and each "bus segment" can have up to 32 PCI devices. In theory, with 4 PCI buses you could have a total 1024 "bus segments" and 32768 PCI devices (including bridges). In practice nobody needs anything that huge.

Comment: @golangboy: Note that PCI specifications describe it like "one bus is multiple bus segments (connected by bridges)". If I wrote the PCI specifications I would've described it as "one group is multiple buses (connected by bridges)" instead. Unfortunately that's how the specification is; and people get sloppy and shorten "bus segment" to "bus" so it gets confusing/ambiguous.

Comment: thanks Brendan.... I understand what you mean, I just wonder: if you connect to the CPU via PCI Host Bridge, then the PCI Bus here is the system bus (or is it the global bus?) If you use ISA Host Bridge (I'm not sure if there is one, just an example) to connect to the CPU, then ISA Bus is the system bus (global bus). right??

Comment: @golangboy: Once upon a time (before PCI existed) computers mainly used ISA bus (although there were others that were less common - MCA, EISA, etc). As things (video cards) became faster the ISA bus became a performance problem; so video card and chipset manufacturers cooperated to create "VESA Local Bus" as a kind of high-speed connection to the (CPU's) local bus. PCI recycled the word "local" for marketing purposes (to promote PCI, or "PCI Local Bus", as a replacement for "VESA Local Bus"). Excluding marketing nonsense; the words "local" (and "global") have nothing to do with PCI buses.

Comment: @golangboy: Mostly; a computer consists of multiple different kinds of buses (and multiple kinds of point-to-point links) working together (e.g. hyper-transport, Quickpath, PCI, ISA, USB, SPI, ...); where none are global, and "local" begs a frame of reference ("local, from which piece of hardware's perspective?").

Comment: Thank you very much! ..... Maybe what I mean by global bus (system bus) is the bus with the most IO devices connected

Comment: South Bridge is called nowadays PCH. Many modern systems from Intel have it, but sometimes it's on the same chip (may or may be not on the same die, though).